# Using custom configuration sources in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, config

I have an application that uses standard Microsoft configuration files (Settings.settings) and standard Microsoft way to access the properties (.Properties.Settings.Default.).

Now want to extend the functionality for following features:

1. User related settings should be searched in in the regkey `"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\<Company>\<Product>"`. If the valuename is found in registry this will used instead of the entry in the local configuration files.
2. Machine related settings should be searched in in the regkey `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\<Company>\<Product>"`. If the valuename is found in registry this will used instead of the entry in the local configuration files.
3. insted of the complex path that is generated by microsoft uniquly for every machine (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<CompanyName>\<Productname>.exe_Url_3uqqmhf5a1wopes52aggyi4dafudcbja\2.0.0.10`) i will use the easier pathname `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<CompanyName>\<Productname>\2.0.0.10`
4. I want to create a custom configuration provider that uses a complete other datasource (Configfile in dropbox, database, what ever).

Edited: Now my question: How can solve this 4 issues (in best case without modifying existing code)?

I think there are some magic Interfaces or some Microsoft classes I have to override. I found some information about this, but I am really confused. Some people write about AppSection, some articles are related to *.settings file, some to app.config. 
Does anyone has an approach/article which explains this in simple words for an .NET Framework 4 application?

Regards

Dave

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you want to do but what is your question?

Comment: Yea, good question. I edited the orignal text. Hopefully it is more clear now.